# crop image from polygon_perimeter

Tags: python, crop, scikit-image

I am attempting to crop the image.
I have created a polygon around the part I want cropped.

```
xs = []
ys = []
for props in measurements:
    minr, minc, maxr, maxc = props.bbox
    by = (minc , maxc, maxc, minc, minc)
    bx = (minr, minr, maxr, maxr, minr)
    xs.append(bx)
    ys.append(by)
    
    
r = xs[0] 
c = ys[0] 


rr,cc = draw.polygon_perimeter(r ,c)
img_blob[rr,cc] = 1
cool = img_blob[rr,cc]

[rows, columns] = np.where(cool)
row1 = min(rows)
row2 = max(rows)
col1 = min(columns)
col2 = max(columns)


cropped = img_blob[row1 : row2, col1:col2]
plt.imshow(cropped)
```

with the code above i am getting the

```
ValueError to be 'not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)'
```

How can I get only where the `polygon_perimeter` is so that I can crop it according to that?

I cannot use `cv2` or `PIL`, only `skimage` or `numpy`

Answer (score 0):

`cool` is a 1-dimensional array containing only 1s, as you extract them from `img_blog` using `cool = img_blob[rr, cc]`. Indexing with lists of coordinates is called [fancy indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), and always gets you an array of the same shape as your indices, which in this case is 1D.

So, when you do `np.where(cool)`, you get a tuple of length 1, with 1d coordinates, but the expression `rows, cols = np.where(cool)` expects two values, so it complains. (It's always good to look at the *line* where the ValueError is raised, in the full traceback.)

Instead, use `rows, columns = np.where(img_blob)`, and things should work!